# Is there any easy way to convert WWF workflow to Azure Logic app

Tags: azure, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

We have Windows Workflow Foundation workflow. Is there any easy ways to convert it to Azure Logic App or Azure flow without recreating. Exporting XAML to Logic app or something similar to that. I think WWF is going to die soon.

Comment: No there is not. Why do you think it will dye? Still used in SharePoint afaik.

Comment: @PeterBons, I could see the fate for WWF which was for Silverlight and now WPF. When there is better technology the older die. Forums says the WWF team is not there too.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1bdc2a53-b9f4-4799-aab0-eb158f81ec3e/workflow-in-the-future?forum=wfprerelease. But I am not the final person to confirm anything. It is my guess based on past experience.

Answer (score 1):

No way. Logic Apps uses Swagger to identify the service contracts nor XAML.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no easy way since Logic Apps uses Swagger to identify the service contracts which is totally different than XAML.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to host your workflow(s) via a `WorkflowServiceHost`. Then you can access your workflows via a web hook / REST call. Logic Apps can then access your workflows via the `ReceiveAndSendReply` activity(s) in your workflow.

I believe a quick approach to implementing this strategy is to:

1. Use the **WCF Workflow Service Application**
2. Move your workflow logic into the XAMLX workflow designer
3. Utilize one (or more) `ReceiveAndSendReply` activity(s) to listen in on web calls in your workflow
4. Implement Swagger on top of the WCF services so Logic Apps can be meshed with your workflow services